# Spark Dataframe changing through execution

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm fairly new to Spark, so most likely I'm having a huge gap in my understanding. Apologies in advance if what you see here is very silly. So, what I'm trying to achieve is:

- Get a set of rows from a table in Hive (let's call it **T_A**) and save them in a DataFrame (let's call it DF_A). This is done.
- Get extra information from another Hive table (**T_B**) and join it with DF_A to get a new Dataframe (DF_B). And then **cache it.** This is also done.

```
val DF_A = sparkSession.sql("select * from T_A where whatever=something").toDF()
val extraData = sparkSession.sql("select * from T_B where whatever=something").toDF()

val DF_B = DF_A.join(extraData,
            col(something_else=other_thing), "left"
        ).toDF().cache()
```

Now this is me assuming Spark + Hive works similarly than regular java app + SQL, which is where I might need a hard course correction.

- Here, I attempt to store in one of the Hive Tables I used before (T_B), partitioned by column X, whatever N rows I transformed (Tr1(DF_B)) from DF_B. I use:

```
val DF_C = DF_B.map(row => {
            Tr1(row)
        }).toDF()

DF_C.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("T_B")
```

- After saving it to this table, I want to reuse the information from DF_B (not the transformed data reinserted in **T_B**, but the joined data in DF_B based on previous state of **T_B**) to make a second transformation over it (Tr2(DF_B)).
- I want to update the same N rows written in T_B with the data transformed by previous step, using an "INSERT OVERWRITE" operation and the same partition column X.

```
val DF_D = DF_B.map(row => {
            Tr2(row)
        }).toDF()

DF_D.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("T_B")
```

What I expect:

- T_B having N rows.
- Having DF_B unchanged, with N rows.

What it's happening:

- DF_B having 3*N rows.
- T_C having 3*N rows.

Now, after some debugging, I found that DF_B has 3*N rows after DF_C write finishes. So DF_B will have 3*N rows too and that will cause T_B to have 3*N rows as well.

So, my question is... Is there a way to retain the original DF_B data and use it for the second map transformation, since it relies on the original DF_B state for the transformation process? Is there a reference somewhere I can read to know why this happens?

EDIT: I don't know if this is useful information, but I log the count of records before and after doing the first write. And I get the following

```
val DF_C = DF_B.map(row => {
            Tr1(row)
        }).toDF()

Logger.info("DF_C.count {} - DF_B.count {}"...
DF_C.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("T_B")
Logger.info("DF_C.count {} - DF_B.count {}"...
```

With persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK) or no persist at all, instead of cache and 3 test rows. I get:

> DF_C.count 3 - DF_B.count 3

> write

> DF_C.count 3 - DF_B.count 9

With cache, I get:

> DF_C.count 3 - DF_B.count 3

> write

> DF_C.count 9 - DF_B.count 9

Any idea?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, execution happens in lazy way, only when action gets called.
So when you calling some action two times on same dataframe (in your case DF_B) that dataframe(DB_B) will be created and transformed two times from starting at time of execution.

So try to persist your dataframe DF_B before calling first action, then you can use same DF for both Tr1 and Tr2.

After persist dataframe will be stored in memory/disk and can be reused multiple times.

You can learn more about persistance [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence)

Comment: I tried adding:

DF_B.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

Before 
val DF_C = DF_B.map...

Logging the record count before and after the first write with a 3 row test initially in DF_B, I get:
count DF_C: 3 DF_B: 3
count DF_C: 3 DF_B: 9. 
Am i doing something wrong to eagerly writing on T_C and keeping DF_B unchanged?

Comment: Basically, the results are unchanged from original problem.